# Laravel 5.3 Counter Visitor Page

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a counter page, on the website

here is my Controller PostController:

```
public function show(Post $post)
    {
        $post->increment('view_count');

        return view("site.show", compact('post'));
    }
```

and here is my RouteServiceProvider :

```
public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Route::bind('post', function ($slug) {
            return Post::published()->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        });
    }
```

This code is working, but i have a problem, every time i refresh the page, the field('view_count') in my posts tabel always increment, the question is how to restrict the same visitor for doing the same action like refresh page and so on, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may keep inside the session an array of ids of posts, and checking before doing the query if he didn't already see it. You could also store the timestamp of the view if you'd like to invalidate these.

```
public function show(Post $post)
    {
        $ids = Session::get('ids') ? Session::get('ids') : [];
        if (!in_array($post->id, $ids)) {
          $post->increment('view_count');
          $ids[] = $post->id;
          Session::put('ids', $ids);
        }
        return view("site.show", compact('post'));
    }
```